# Let $x,y,z\in[0,1]$. Find the maximum value of $\sqrt{|x-y|}+\sqrt{|y-z|}+\sqrt{|z-x|}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $x,y,z\in[0,1]$. Then find the maximum value of $\sqrt{|x-y|}+\sqrt{|y-z|}+\sqrt{|z-x|}$.

Now the given answer is $2\sqrt{2}$ but I am not able to obtain the corresponding values of $x,y,z$. Though when I take $|x-y|=|y-z|=\frac{1}{2}$ and $|x-z|=1$, I do obtain $1+\sqrt{2}$. Can there be a proper method to get to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

WLOG fix $x\geq y\geq z$. Then our expression $E$ is
$$E=\sqrt{x-y}+\sqrt{y-z}+\sqrt{x-z}$$
Now, note that as $x$ increases, so does $E$ and so for the maximum value of $E$ we should have $x=1$. Similarly, as $z$ increases, $E$ decreases so we want $z=0$. Then, the expression reduces to
$$E=1+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{1-y}$$
which I hope you can take from here.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: When I take the derivative (in my head), I find the extremum is $y=\frac 12$, which yields $E=1+\sqrt 2$, not $2 \sqrt 2$.

Comment: @RobertShore: And that's correct. The OP probably misread the answer. It is the question 3 in the [paper](http://kvpy.iisc.ac.in/main/resources/2021/STREAM_SX-SB.pdf) and the [answer key](http://kvpy.iisc.ac.in/main/resources/2021/KVPY_SB-SX.pdf) rightly shows the answer, option A which is $1+\sqrt2$.

Comment: +1! If it was my answer, I would also add the final hint to use $y=\sin^2 \alpha$ in my answer at the end.

Comment: @User: Why couldn't I think of that? That's so cool. The way I would prove it originally was using the QM-AM inequality.